# How do I send PHP SMTP Mail (PEAR) without it going to spam because of X-From-Rewrite

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I have a PHP SMTP mail script using the PEAR package Mail. But my emails keep on going to spam on Outlook and Yahoo only. I think its because of

"X-From-Rewrite: rewritten was: [ no-repl@@omadahq.com], actual sender does not match"

This is my script

```
        <?php
            include "Mail.php";
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->reset_email);

            $link = 'https://www.omadahq.com/dashboard/password.php?token='.$token;
            $reply  = "no-reply@omadahq.com";
            $subject = "OmadaHQ Password Reset";
            $from = "OmadaHQ < no-reply@omadahq.com >";
            $to = $name." < ".$email." > ";
            $mailer = 'PHP/' . phpversion();

            $content = "<p>Hello! <br> You have requested a reset to your password, click the button below to reset your password</p><br><br><a href='".$link."' target='_blank'><button style='background: #2196F3; padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px; color: white; border:none'>Reset</button></a><br><br><small>Ignore this message if you did not request a password rest</small>";
            $message = "
                <html lang='en' style='font-size: 15px; font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif; line-height: 28px;'>
                    <center>
                        <body style='margin:0px; width: 100%'>
                            <table style='border-spacing: 0px; min-width: 502px'>
                                <thead>
                                    <td style='background: #2196f3; width: 100%; height: 70px'>
                                        <span style='margin: 25px 0px 25px 25px; color: #FDFFFC'>OmadaHQ</span><small style='font-size: 10px; color: white;'>BETA</small>
                                    </td>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <td style='background: #f1f1f1!important; width: 100%; min-height: 1000px; padding: 50px'>".$content."</td>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </center>
                </html>";
            $host = "ssl://omadahq.com";
            $port = "465";
            $username = "no-reply@omadahq.com";
            //not actual password
            $password = "mypass";
            $headers = array (
                'From' => $from,
                'Reply-To' => $reply,
                'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
                'To' => $to,
                'Subject' => $subject,
                'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
            );

            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                                  array ('host' => $host,
                                         'port' => $port,
                                         'auth' => true,
                                         'username' => $username,
                                         'password' => $password)
                                 );

            $mail = $smtp->send($email, $headers, $message);
            if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
                echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
            } else {
                echo"success";
            }

        }
    ?>
```

And this is the raw message Yahoo

```
        X-Apparently-To: abdul.amoud@yahoo.com; Tue, 16 Jan 2018 03:19:35 +0000
        Return-Path: <no-reply@omadahq.com>
        X-YahooFilteredBulk: 162.213.253.118
        Received-SPF: pass (domain of omadahq.com designates 162.213.253.118 as permitted sender)
        X-YMailISG: MAHoRIoWLDsd1bQoQ7Xtnqqhx06aGQQ76azf.M8umhJeDTXG
         vuyAqybAiVp7fBJosERRLqsl.9lqJvBXgPVJ_6M8MvsKv5k6028MpxVSLZm_
         xc5Obf3P77hY6s509EySS7ORLVXaOKJ3xp9DIDcZVkwg5.JNB15HoLLdUolB
         njOtnZpwiniXenQxDXfgWUlBTjm0aPU7425krSi4l.5vycsxe8LE9g_ln3SJ
         _ywLAoTUfnanmh1jKSRtGGbCF4i_Qv8suvaUmkdGdp5W6EaIQ5KlTcVBWJDP
         Bo3F55sXUqkoEzKiXpJtu.GF12HvOMoRYNzcNZRnf0RuSyZH1EIco50k_r9R
         zaDZ0trJ9VPxwqi9UCTMc3XtV30roCVr9an.TVm27tVdB9xacbkU9G3qTAYH
         GUP.4qRLNX1FABkedWk6Kh.QWnQnmLsxPTdYPwuBvY2UPSNdxkTXcvkxPBA.
         6nOVntAeaMamHD9dGNzFXLtyVGONSBPDtYnL.AlIIlSQO7zmWBKKWhJMlnz8
         ohPq90gK0vQntYO2tO6UIp7W9eUo1lSpajnPYAUfIOVqyt3bVi6lTV1akbij
         .AJG7UllXtov53su.NM_D9W0gnMYyIc9lSTA5oRQsKXdpSueTdBqVUDC5FLt
         I0flgGBR1buQN77eJx774xrmXzDcUfetoQ_dT5Zq5FDQy5oAbg_Z2FsAbKNV
         cYVX_pk92xsI.EzLMw4BCtvgQ0hq95k253IrScu5J3xLWW7KfkR2RnJxz3th
         xANzU3ebzZ3VX96qGSD2dkNrwh0e5.C0OcprCFFeg09kWytmRJeNRpCaPXth
         6RzTbvIca6Ydx7YL0_.98umCJLKzG7hnQu5zgwy4Z1gjVxDOG7BPSxgin0HV
         k39.JVswb4OydFNCEIt3_gNavSXyjMAI9_qXxXgCLqmSolEP66og57NK0kES
         glxts9_cItezElwgPH.StnNt2H8XyP3Al5MCUEyGjuc73EJOLH6t0RnBFpx.
         a5rAAI.lLgTJpP_rCjucgBMvtzQgLAlKRkPgIb_B4nHm0lU.lIGtynFTabOw
         9iut7gr5yVsF0fHl6cMwm73rvPaH8kW1296UOMUKzUaqXZTik_tjw.d45Coy
         uhq0O7TehT8lgjbnKlrixbCZPmF.kBiJq_UcDHpLNKN7xs4SvyuEUFEeQpDx
         c3fjaI6N.anjRswYujiXUPhKwqheCZFG.yDgYKo4KEsvOn8e0HS9HJnafysA
         cfC51CiqHjXMwn0FeosOEheVTtThH8u.xMpK62ZYxb0dYXhve4AOh.nlz5wP
         wyjKLUdC2M_i9aBugZtcpf.7iEZa7gm4Rxvp8qekoDxzkuLIjjqOxmoQbh_U
         kzKMjrUig8cSR2ngRUB45ViBSYKed3bc64tsRFD.ANOZJPecIUtv1Ndq39aW
        X-Originating-IP: [162.213.253.118]
        Authentication-Results: mta4110.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=omadahq.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=omadahq.com; dkim=pass (ok)
        Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO server191-2.web-hosting.com) (162.213.253.118)
          by mta4110.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Tue, 16 Jan 2018 03:19:35 +0000
        DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=omadahq.com
            ; s=default; h=Content-type:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Reply-To:From:Sender:Date
            :Message-ID:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description:
            Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:
            In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:
            List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
            bh=qPT08qjIupdd89pV7Rwm7KHerd4Wk1LRYXNCO6on9Oo=; b=wn/OLREow4kj0ff2RhCOUY/UZ/
            kizvKtDFWLqj3Ibrz22YA0c/euSwiFPfnApBYT34ShL2jQjekRrR0sVJ3IG2WbsrjT7uL8KS07iJo
            ejpkVdRQkezumnxK7KvNAVIugtZSX9WGRoFqDTayIdMoUOJaCO/Jd9vtvV2Se7wdYmWRvGbbVELG0
            tWSPGYALiOF57h9G91buOuBMk4dA+z/h+W5Gz4+7anWhbTF3ScsmXY8g47nb6nU8NG8wsu+EXZWKN
            5EYWj+wX1cVhtdWnjfsLp61fjENUHzECUmE+CiPyc62Sq6E81pqvtmrujN1fQt3SRwHTKRX8fngSq
            hnpuu9OQ==;
        Received: from apportal.ca ([162.213.253.118]:34242 helo=localhost)
            by server191.web-hosting.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128)
            (Exim 4.89)
            (envelope-from <no-reply@omadahq.com>)
            id 1ebHme-004F3h-KK
            for abdul.amoud@yahoo.com; Mon, 15 Jan 2018 22:19:33 -0500
        From: OmadaHQ <no-reply@omadahq.com >
        Reply-To: no-reply@omadahq.com
        MIME-Version: 1.0
        To: Abdul Amoud < abdul.amoud@yahoo.com > 
        Subject: OmadaHQ Password Reset
        Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
        X-OutGoing-Spam-Status: No, score=4.4
        X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
        X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server191.web-hosting.com
        X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - yahoo.com
        X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
        X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - omadahq.com
        X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server191.web-hosting.com: authenticated_id: no-reply@omadahq.com
        X-Authenticated-Sender: server191.web-hosting.com: no-reply@omadahq.com
        X-Source: 
        X-Source-Args: 
        X-Source-Dir: 
        X-From-Rewrite: rewritten was: [ no-repl@@omadahq.com], actual sender does not match
        Content-Length: 1507


                            <html lang='en' style='font-size: 15px; font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif; line-height: 28px;'>
                                <center>
                                    <body style='margin:0px; width: 100%'>
                                        <table style='border-spacing: 0px; min-width: 502px'>
                                            <thead>
                                                <td style='background: #2196f3; width: 100%; height: 70px'>
                                                    <span style='margin: 25px 0px 25px 25px; color: #FDFFFC'>OmadaHQ</span><small style='font-size: 10px; color: white;'>BETA</small>
                                                </td>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <td style='background: #f1f1f1!important; width: 100%; min-height: 1000px; padding: 50px'><p>Hello! <br> You have requested a reset to your password, click the button below to reset your password</p><br><br><a href='https://www.omadahq.com/dashboard/password.php?token=aa20727a7e6b3ec534d3dfafb4c44224fa5d5452' target='_blank'><button style='background: #2196F3; padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px; color: white; border:none'>Reset</button></a><br><br><small>Ignore this message if you did not request a password rest</small></td>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </body>
                                </center>
                            </html>
```

How does Roundcube and wordpress do it? I have them both on my host space, and they don't seem to have this problem when mail is sent from my space. Please help. Do not suggest third parties. There is a way for this to work no need to use a third party that will charge me or restrict my service.

Comment: theres various dns headers that can help improve it

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the yahoo issue. It was caused by the spaces in the From variable.

OmadaHQ `< no-reply@omadahq.com >`

to

OmadaHQ `<no-reply@omadahq.com>`

Still having the issue with Outlook.